# Scrolling PreferenceFragment with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview, preferencefragment

I am trying to build `PreferenceFragment` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The problem is that there are too many elements in `PreferenceFragment` and they are not displayed. It seems like `NestedScrollView` is not working with these fragments. Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217741/preferencefragment-with-collapsingtoolbarlayout) doesn't work for me, because I can't use compat library for other reasons. How can I resolve this issue?

**Code:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:showIn="@layout/activity_user_profile">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/user_profile_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by compat library ?

Comment: i mean support preference library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

okay after a long time I figured out that `PreferenceFragment` uses `ListView` to display its elements which in turn doesn't work inside `NestedScrollView`. I solved it by overriding `onViewCreated` method in `PreferenceFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    final ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    if (lv != null)
        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(lv, true);
}
```

Hope this helps someone